# sql group by with different lines

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Name | City1 | City2 | City3 |
------------------------------
Nike | Oslo  |       |       |
Nike |       | Oran  |       |
Nike |       |       | Riga  |
```

I want the output to be:

```
Name | City1 | City2 | City3 |
------------------------------
Nike | Oslo  | Oran  | Riga  |
```

Looks simple but I can't figure out how?
I would be very grateful for help

Comment: `select max(name), max(city1), max(city2), max(city2) from t` ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eca82/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT Name,
  MAX(City1) City1,
  MAX(City2) City2, 
  MAX(City3) City3
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Name
```

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c14e48cd25db061f97acf33bdfeb7004)

Answer (score 0):

Use `STRING_AGG` or `GROUP_CONCAT` depends on which DB you use if there are multiple values in the same column for the same key.

```sql
SELECT Name,
  STRING_AGG(City1, ',') City1,
  STRING_AGG(City2, ',') City2, 
  STRING_AGG(City3, ',') City3
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Name
```